# Calculate the current CPU and memory utilization of pods as a percentage of its requests and limits

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks

I am trying to setup Grafana alerts on the actual CPU and memory utilization for pods as a percentage of its requests and limits.

I have kube prometheus installed on EKS cluster and have kube-state-metrics as well.

In my understanding, kube-state-metrics is not exposing current utilization metrics such as current CPU and memory usage for the pod. It just gives details of the objects installed. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Reading through some [documentation](https://www.kubecost.com/kubernetes-devops-tools/cadvisor/), it seems like cadvisor can get me these details. The doc suggest to run it as a daemon set.
The [Github link](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) for cadvisor also talks about running it as a docker container

However, there are a couple of things I want to verify

a) Isn't cadvisor already installed as a part of the kubelet binary?
My understanding is stemming from the k8s documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/system-metrics/)

b) If yes, then with my kube-prometheus setup, how can i get all the metrics that cadvisor exposes? Should I create a new service monitor CR or a pod monitor CR to scrape these cadvisor metrics.

c) Does the node exporter already capture these metrics at /metrics/cadvisor? I have the node exporter installed. Can i configure the node exporter to capture these metrics.

How can I get the current CPU and memory utilization of my pods to my prometheus DB?

Comment: Have you installed the metrics server yet? https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server